# Why would my goji berry plant in California get sick and full of aphids?

Tags: diagnosis, berries, aphids, goji

I live in Los Angeles, California. I bought two goji berry plants on-line two years ago. The aphids already killed one. I thought it killed the other one but it grew back. I know that plants have defenses against bugs. The most logical explanation is it is sick. Maybe it doesn't have enough nutrients. So what would be the best way to make a goji berry plant healthy? I only had berries from it one time.

Now that May is coming I want a garden in my back yard, but with all those aphids attacking it will spill into my garden. I want to save it if I can. I was using Neem oil extract for the aphids. The leaves are all yellow, it is a mess. Should I just cut the leaves all off?

Comment: Can you add a photo or two please - it might be apparent from photos whether the plants have other problems besides aphid infestation

Comment: Welcome to the site! As Bamboo said, some pictures would be really helpful. Can you show us the whole plant, and close-ups of both sides of the leaves? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure these are aphids or something else?

Comment: It was doing well and growing beautiful now it has some kind of spider web all over I sprayed them off and spray neem oil all over it. And what look like orange eggs under the spider web. I think I will get Calcium Nitrate he talks about. I was giving it Fish oil and Sea weed extract a while back but I got real sick and did not give it attention for a while.

Comment: @AmberCrystal Does it look like spider mites?

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't bother with insecticides for aphids, although they could get rid of them, probably. I recommend getting a [shower nozzle](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0187BOHPW) for your hose and showering the foliage every two or three days. Aphids don't tend to stay on regularly showered plants. I didn't have any issues with plants I did that with in 2016, except when I wasn't doing it. It should spray the aphids off, but I don't think that's exactly why it works. The plants seem more resistant to them for some reason. I didn't have whitefly issues either. It also helps against spider mites. It made my plants grow a lot faster, too.

Anyway, if your plants get fungal diseases from humidity and rain easily, this may not be the best suggestion.

Insects can also spread disease, however.

Also, hard water might damage leaves by leaving mineral deposits.

Whatever the case, don't just use a regular hose without a nozzle to spray your plants. It doesn't seem to work and is likely to splash more soil on your foliage, which can hinder growth, and according to many, bring diseases to your foliage.

The Orbit 58993 Control Contractor Turret Pistol Spray Nozzle is the one I use. It's durable and works well, but it lacks a soaker setting (so I use a dedicated soaker piece when I want that).

It's possible that the goji berries aren't very acclimated to your soil and/or growing conditions. This may result in weaker plants. They'll probably do better in the future some time, as long as you get rid of your pests.

In my experience, fertilizing with calcium nitrate (foliar spray) can deter aphids, but make sure you could use the calcium/nitrogen, first. It doesn't deter ladybugs.

Ladybugs and lacewings may also help.

Comment: Now it is spider web please refer to above. And thank you for your help.